# how can I determine the y delta of sub tag in p tag

Tags: html

I have a very long text in a p tag, this text contains a lot of sup footnotes.

how can i determine the y offset of these sup tags, i want to display the footnotes to the left of the text.

```
<p>Wir Herman von <bold>Wachtendungk,<sup>2</sup></bold> von Gots gnaden Abt des Gotshuiss und herre zu Sieberg, <bold>vort<sup>3</sup></bold> gantz gemein Convent ordens sanct Benedicti, inn dem <bold>gestichte<sup>4</sup></bold> vonn Collenn gelegenn, Thun sementlichenn khundt allenn luiden unnd bekennen ...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an offset relative to the page you can try something like

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('sup');
Array.from(elements).forEach(element => {
    const clientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const clientX = clientRect.left;
    console.log(clientX); // this is your offset
});
```

If you need an offset relative to the enclosing <p> element

```
// select your p here
const p = document.getElementById(...);
const bounds = p.getBoundingClientRect();
const pOffset = bounds.left;
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName(sup);
Array.from(elements).forEach(element => {
    const clientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const clientX = clientRect.left;
    console.log(clientX - pOffset); // this is your offset
})
```